# Ember-cli css minification is removing quotes and spaces

Tags: css, sass, ember-cli, minify

Is there a way that I can disable some minifying rules when launching the ember-cli build?
I have this CSS selector

```
[attribute*="value" i]
```

And the minified version returns

```
[attribute*=valuei]
```

Which is kind of a problem because the framework is based on that way of selecting classes through combined parts that join in a single camelCase class name within the HTML, which is the reason why I need the "i" (case-**i**nsensitive). So unless I change all camelCase classes with its hyphen separated version and remove the "i" from everywhere, nothing is going to work

Ideally I'd like to prevent the minifier from removing spaces or from removing quotes.

Any idea?! maybe some other options to pass here:

```
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    minifyCSS: {
      options: { processImport: true }
    }
  });

  //...
  return app.toTree();
};
```

Thanks in advance